# Unwanted animations coming from nowhere

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, addsubview

In my iOS app, I have some animations that seem to be coming out of nowhere. They don't happen at first, only after using the app a little. Here is a Youtube video with a better description:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whfG67EP6kk

I'm not really sure why the elements are animating the way they are (or at all). The code I'm calling is just a simple [view addSubView:viewname]. Any help as to how this is happening and how to prevent it would be great.

**EDIT**
Here is the code for the text that comes flying in from seemingly all directions:

```
-(void)displayPublicDataForEntry:(PFObject *)entry likes:(unsigned long)likesCount comments:(unsigned long)commentsCount
{
    [indicator stopAnimating];
    [indicator removeFromSuperview];
    [zippingLabel removeFromSuperview];

    entryStatus.text = @"This entry is public";
    entryStatus.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    entryStatus.frame = CGRectMake(10, 3, 200, 20);
    [shareView addSubview:entryStatus];

    // Display a UILabel of number of likes
    if (likesCount == 1)
        numberOfLikes.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu like", likesCount];
    else
        numberOfLikes.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu likes", likesCount];

    CGSize stringsize = [numberOfLikes.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];

    numberOfLikes.frame = CGRectMake(10, 22, stringsize.width, 20);
    numberOfLikes.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [shareView addSubview:numberOfLikes];

    // Display a UILabel of number of comments
    if (commentsCount == 1)
        numberOfComments.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" / %lu comment", commentsCount];
    else
        numberOfComments.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" / %lu comments", commentsCount];

    numberOfComments.frame = CGRectMake(numberOfLikes.frame.size.width + 10, 22, 100, 20);
    numberOfComments.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [shareView addSubview:numberOfComments];

    viewEntry.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 95, 12, 100, 40);
    [viewEntry addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(viewPublicEntry)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [shareView addSubview:viewEntry];
}
```

There's nothing in there (at least I don't think there is) that would cause these strange animations.

Comment: No code that you doubt may be causing this?

Comment: Well, that's the thing... I'm only calling addSubview. I'm certainly not explicitly animating anything. I'll add the code for the view with the text that comes flying in from all directions.

Comment: For the moment, I've fixed the problem by wrapping the functions that add the views in between [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO]; and [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];. Bizarre, but it's working. I'm gonna leave the question open in case someone comes up with a root cause and solution.

Comment: I've seen these animations in other apps, like Facebook. It must be something built into iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. The cause ended up being a call to begin animations without a call to commit.  I somehow called [UIView beginAnimations:Nil context:nil] twice.